# Change svg fill within the div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am trying to create a div(button) with an animation effect when user hover over div the span and image inside the div change the color. 
The issue is that I can't figure out is:
 1. Is it possible to keep images loaded in .svg and the fill within JS code?
2. And if there a way to load the .svg images with a way shorter code that I did it in this example?


P.S: In the snippet I've displayed the result that I am willing to achieve except a transition effect on image color change.

```js
function changeMe() {
  var block = document.getElementById('block');
  block.src = ('http://s8.postimg.org/q8p6g28cx/image.png');
  $('#text').addClass('light-blue-link');
}

function changeMeBack() {
  var block = document.getElementById('block');
  block.src = ('http://s8.postimg.org/e5f9er7wx/image.png');
  $('#text').removeClass('light-blue-link');
}
```

```css
span {
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

.light-blue-link {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

.image {
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button::before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='bookmark' class='button' onmouseover="changeMe()" onmouseout="changeMeBack()">
  
  <img id='block' class='image' src="http://s8.postimg.org/e5f9er7wx/image.png">
  <span id='text' class=''>Bookmarks</span>
  
</div>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g id="star">
  <polygon fill="#3C3B3C" points="50,78.576 80.591,97.025 72.498,62.232 99.5,38.833 63.905,35.779 50,2.975 36.096,35.779 
   0.5,38.833 27.502,62.232 19.409,97.025   "/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your first point is unclear, and the second is no - there's no way to shorten what you have as you need to define all points of the shape. Although you can get rid of the (very odd) XML declaration in the middle of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function changeMe() {
  var block=document.getElementById('block');
  block.src=('http://s8.postimg.org/q8p6g28cx/image.png');
  $('#text').addClass('light-blue-link');
 $('polygon').css('fill','rgb(88, 202, 230)')
}

function changeMeBack() {
  var block=document.getElementById('block');
  block.src=('http://s8.postimg.org/e5f9er7wx/image.png');
  $('#text').removeClass('light-blue-link');
  $('polygon').css('fill','#3C3B3C')
}
```

```css
span {
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

.light-blue-link {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}
.image {
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id='bookmark' class='button' onmouseover="changeMe()" onmouseout="changeMeBack()">

  <img id='block' class='image' src="http://s8.postimg.org/e5f9er7wx/image.png">
  <span id='text' class=''>Bookmarks</span>

</div>


        <svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g id="star">
        <polygon fill="#3C3B3C" points="50,78.576 80.591,97.025 72.498,62.232 99.5,38.833 63.905,35.779 50,2.975 36.096,35.779 
   0.5,38.833 27.502,62.232 19.409,97.025   " />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the SVG isn't in the div so the hover only applies to the div contents. I also moved to jQuery 3 so that addClass works with SVG elements. I've removed much of the unnecessary code you put in your SVG too.

```js
function changeMe() {
  var block = document.getElementById('block');
  block.src = ('http://s8.postimg.org/q8p6g28cx/image.png');
  $('#text').addClass('light-blue-link');
  $('polygon').addClass('light-blue-link');
}

function changeMeBack() {
  var block = document.getElementById('block');
  block.src = ('http://s8.postimg.org/e5f9er7wx/image.png');
  $('#text').removeClass('light-blue-link');
  $('polygon').removeClass('light-blue-link');
}
```

```css
span {
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

.light-blue-link {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
  fill: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

.image {
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button::before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>

<div id='bookmark' class='button' onmouseover="changeMe()" onmouseout="changeMeBack()">
  
  <img id='block' class='image' src="http://s8.postimg.org/e5f9er7wx/image.png">
  <span id='text' class=''>Bookmarks</span>
  
</div>

<svg id="Слой_1" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<g>
 <g id="star" fill="#3C3B3C">
  <polygon points="50,78.576 80.591,97.025 72.498,62.232 99.5,38.833 63.905,35.779 50,2.975 36.096,35.779 
   0.5,38.833 27.502,62.232 19.409,97.025"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```